# How do I determine what font I get for a requested font in Java?

Tags: java, fonts, 2d

When I request a font under Java, if that font does not exist, I need to determine what font it maps to (so I can log the mapping in use). Under Java 1.6 I could use:

```
Font logicalFont = new java.awt.Font(fontname, java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 12);

for (int i = 0; i < FontManager.getRegisteredFonts().length; i++) {
    Font2D font2D = FontManager.getRegisteredFonts()[i];
    if (font2D instanceof CompositeFont && font2D.getFontName(Locale.getDefault()).equals(logicalFont.getFontName())) {
        PhysicalFont physicalFont = ((CompositeFont) font2D).getSlotFont(0);
        log.warn("The requested font '" + fontname + "' does not exist on this system. Substituting the font '" + physicalFont.getFamilyName(Locale.getDefault()) + "'");
        return;
    }
}
```

But in Java 1.7 FontManager has no getRegisteredFonts() static member (I think it's actually an interface now). So how can I get the mapping?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/java2d/SunGraphicsEnvironment.html.  There seem to be methods there, like getAllFonts(), that do what getRegisteredFonts used to do.